# IS CS 1.6 compatiable with reverse proxy based DDOS protection

Tags: counter-strike

My CS 1.6 game servers are getting DDOS-ed. I have since then purchased a reverse proxy based DDOS protection which supports both TCP and UDP ports. But I have not been able to setup the game properly. The game server is alive in [Game tracker](http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/95.141.42.169:27015/), but when I connect using the game client it fails to connect. But the actual IP 46.249.199.73:27015 is running and I am able to connect to that.

Could you please tell me if it is even possible to setup the kind of thing I am and if it is how do I do that?

These are the ports that I have opened in the reverse proxy manage area

1200-1200 UDP
27000-27015 UDP
27030-27039 TCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's been many years since I had posted this questions and over the time I have learnt quite a bit about tackling DDOS attacks on my game hosting servers. Thought it might help others to know how I was finally able to mitigate the attacks.

The best solution that worked for me was setting a GRE tunnel between my actual server and a front facing server from any of the DDOS filtering services.

Comment: Don't forget you can self-accept if you feel it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems a little off-topic for this site but depending on where this server is (If you're running it out of your house) You could have a look into messing with the apache module called Mod_Evasive as explained by our sister site [Security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/35387/snort-ids-detect-and-alert-on-possible-dos-ddos-attack) I was going to have you look into a program called Snort as well but do keep in mind that these are based on having administrator access to a linux machine.

If what I'm saying sounds like gibberish then you should request this information from your hosts and see if they are actively protecting against DDoS attacks.

If connecting directly to the IP works, then you could use [No-IP](http://www.noip.com) for a free domain redirect to the IP address as well.

It also sounds as though the domain name may be misconfigured if you are able to connect to the IP as if you were being [DDoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)'ed then the ENTIRE SERVER would lag down and falter out on any form of connection.

Comment: No the server runs on a dedicated server.